# Trim start and end points of straight line to where they enter/exit a rectangle?

Tags: math, trigonometry, vector-graphics, clipping, cartesian-coordinates

I'm doing some canvas painting, and for performance reasons I want to get the coordinate of where a straight line enters and/or exits the screen.

To put it more simply, I want to find out the coordinates `A'` and `B'` in the illustration below. `A` and `B` are the original start- and end coordinates. `A'` and `B'` are the coordinates where the straight line from `A` to `B` enters or exits the screen bounds.

This seems like something that would be a common scenario, but I can't really find a simple and efficient algorithm for it.

[image]

I'm using Flutter, but I guess this is a general problem with a similar solution no matter which language (A and B are points, the screen is a rect).

Comment: Not sure this is of help in your specific case but [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is quite useful for spatial analyses.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the following parameters and equations:

- points A and B are given by their respective coordinates `(xA, yA)` and `(xB, yB)`;
- the bounding box is given by the 4 inequations `xMin <= x; x <= xMax; yMin <= y; y <= yMax`;
- line (AB) is given by its equation `(y-yA)*(xB-xA) = (yB-yA)*(x-A)`.

We can use them to solve for the intersection points:

- In the first two examples, you can find the coordinates `(x,y)` of `A'` by setting `y=yMax` and solving the line equation for `x`;
- In the first example, you can find the coordinates `(x,y)` of `B'` by setting `x=xMax` and solving the line equation for `y`;
- In the third example, you can find the coordinates `(x,y)` of `B'` by setting `y=yMin` and solving the line equation for `x`.

To find all intersection points with the bounding box in all possible case, you could solve the equations for all 4 possible types of intersections, then discard solutions which either:

- do not satisfy the bounding box inequations (those solutions are intersections with the "continuations" of the sides of the bounding box); or
- do not satisfy the inequations of the implicit bounding box around segment [AB] (those solutions are intersections of the line (AB) with the bounding box, and of no interest to you if you want only the intersections of the segment [AB] with the bounding box).